# How to center icon from Skycon through css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this Weather App for Free Code Camp and I've decided to use some icons from Skycons: http://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/

However, no matter how hard I try, I can't change the alignment of the icon on my page.

How can I center the div containing the icon? I tried making two col-xs-6: one with the weather aligned to the right, and the other with the icon aligned to the left, but the icon wouldn't budge, no matter what I try.

These are the two elements that I wanted to align:

```
<div id = "weather"></div> 
<div class ="pass"><canvas id = "clear-day" height = "24"></canvas></div>
```

And this is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/Thiagoral/pen/BQXOvW

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on your intended result but adding `text-align:center` to the `<div class="body">` element results in the Skycon being centered...

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I intended. I wonder why I couldn't change just by fiddling with the id css though.

Comment: Cool - I'll post it as the answer & you can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the canvas'd icon to be centered as described, you should apply a `text-align:center` to the parent element.

```
.body {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Forked pen with solution applied:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbNPER

Answer (score 0):

you can center it by giving the clear-day canvas the following css properties:

```
#clear-day {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
```

}

I hope this helps you out